# negación en expresión lambda y Entity c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

tengo un pequeño inconveniente, estoy intentando hacer una comparativa de datos, estoy haciendo una validación de un objeto con una información que le añado mientras consumo un servicio res. ..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información hay algunas existentes en sql y otras que se irán agregando con el transcurrir de los días, intento validar esa información con una expresión lambdas y al momento de guardar dicha información (si se encuentra o no) entra y guarda los cambios...

```
if ( entities.proveedores.Any(x => x.pro_codigosap != (prove.pro_codigosap)))

                {
                    entities.SaveChanges();

                }
```

hacerlo así, tira "True" e intenta guardar los cambios en la BD pero como esa data existe y es código único, tira error de ForeKey.

si le agrego éste código:

```
if ( entities.proveedores.Any(x => !x.pro_codigosap.Equals(prove.pro_codigosap)))
{
   entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

de igual manera entra y me tira el error.

Lo que realmente necesito hacer es validar la información de mi obj prove contra mi data de la tabla proveedores.

para que el api sepa cuando tiene que guardar la información y cuando no.

¡GRACIAS!.

Comment: Podrias mirar el [tour]? no entiendo la logica. si vos comparas toda la tabla contra un codigo en particular, por supuesto que va a dar true, porque any va a devolver cualquiera. faltara algun filtro ahi?

Comment: la tabla se llama proveedores y el campo que quiero comparar es pro_codigosap @gbianchi

Comment: pero que buscas comparar?

Comment: ahí agregué una foto del código, estoy haciendo una inserción de datos que vienen de una api, hago un match, si el dato no existe en sql hago la inserción sino envió un correo, lo corrí una vez pero cuando a consumir la api me tira error porque ésta haciendo el insert sin validar si la data existe o no.

Comment: hermano, en el sitio, las fotos encajan mejor en el contexto de mostrar errores. Para código, copia y pega, te ayudamos con el formato :D

Comment: @fredyfx si ahí la edite, gracias.

Comment: pero un error de `foreign key` no tiene nada que ver con lo que validas, solo verificas la key no las relaciones con otras tablas. Ademas si ya buscaste por el codigo y devolvio null esta claro que esa key no existe en la tabla

Comment: @LeandroTuttini es que el codigosap es un código único, entonces cuando hace insert del objeto que le estoy agregando la información del res ( prove ) al sql explota por error de foreign key, verifiqué y esa data ya existe, por eso intento hacer esa validación previa.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini error de SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_proveedores'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.proveedores'. The duplicate key value is (0).

Comment: cual es al campos que defines como key de la tabla ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini pro_codigosap, key, varchar(10)

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiar la manera de formular tu **if** ya que en el primero estas buscando si hay algo que tenga un **codigoSap** diferente entonces eso no evalúa que tengas el mismo para que no falle. Y en el segundo la verdad que no entiendo que esta negando ahí al hacer el equals. Mi propuesta es que busques con el **.Any()** si ya contiene ese código y en el if principal lo niegues para que únicamente te entre cuando el Any te devuelva falso (que no existe ese código)

```
if (!entities.proveedores.Any(x => x.pro_codigosap == prove.pro_codigosap))
{
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Le agregue un  count > 0 para saber si existe en la bd, sino hacer un save pero al parecer existe un registro que no me aparece en bd pero está en la data que estoy llamando, cuando hace el save (inserción) dice que ya esa data existe y dice: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_proveedores'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.proveedores'. The duplicate key value is (0).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolverlo, resulta que había un registro que el error indica que esa información ya existe pero no esta en SQL Server pero si viene de la respuesta de la API, le coloque un

```
 Try {
        entities.SaveChanges();
        client.Close();
} catch { return "No reventó...";  }
```

para que siguiera ejecutando y terminará así hubiera error.

¡Gracias a todos!.